# Dropdown Vertical Menu Increase submenu width automatically

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, submenu

I created a dropdown vertical menu. The menu is working but the submenu width depends on the parent container/div width, which makes the text and other content to stack.

I can set the parent container as display:block(no width/max) or set a width per item, and solve the problem but I don't  want to do that.

I want the width to be adjusted based on item indifferent of parent width.

The menus are dynamic so I don't know the with prior, displaying block creates "issues" with other elements in the page.

------ CSS --------------

```
.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1; }
  .dropdown__trigger {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0.3125rem; }
  .dropdown__content {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 100%;
    border: 1px solid red;
    visibility: hidden;
    transform: translateY(15px);
    opacity: 0;
    background: #fff; }
  .dropdown__item {
    padding: 1rem;
    display: inline-block; }
  .dropdown .dropdown .dropdown__content {
    left: 100%;
    top: 0; }
  .dropdown:hover > .dropdown__content {
    transform: translateY(0);
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity 0.3s, visibility 0.3s, transform 0.3s;
    visibility: visible; }
```

---- HTMl ---------------
------- disregard inline styles are for development purpose only -------

```
<div class="grid" style="width:150px;">
<div class="dropdown">
    <a class="button--primary dropdown__trigger ">Dropdown</a>

    <div class="dropdown__content">
        <a class="dropdown__item" href="#">Action Something else here</a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown__item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>

        <div class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown__trigger">trig</a>
            <div class="dropdown__content">
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                <div class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown__trigger">Dropdown</a>
                    <div class="dropdown__content">
                        <li><a class="button--primary dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div style="width:340px;">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin vitae tincidunt nunc. Praesent eu sagittis
        ex, eu viverra leo. Sed quam felis, tincidunt ut nibh in, condimentum aliquet enim. Etiam malesuada semper sem,
        ac fermentum purus facilisis eu. Vestibulum ut ipsum tortor. Mauris non dui eu odio condimentum interdum.
        Fusce commodo, nulla vitae vulputate
        mollis, sapien massa convallis eros, id tempor lectus erat sit amet velit. Sed quis ante ut augue congue
        malesuada vitae at ipsum. Nulla non libero eu risus elementum lobortis </p>
</div>
</div>
```

How can I solve this ? (I know there are a lot of menus out there, but I want to create my own solution, to learn and understand)

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/aJwKVg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can add this style to your .dropdown__content class.

```
white-space: nowrap;
```

For elements inside like div I succeeded when I set their width auto. It makes sense because when you display block element is trying to fit its parent. But when you set its width to auto while displaying block it takes its width from its content.

Comment: Are you sure? Which browser you are testing it. Because I just inserted a div with width of 800px and it worked.

Comment: Firefox 45ESR; is working because you set the width of the div; if I set the width is working even without white-space nowrap; the thing is I don't know the width, the content is dynamic, based on user choices and backend vars

Comment: Changed answer accordingly.